# PyCharm import multiple functions from the same module

Tags: python, import, pycharm

I have a small annoyance with PyCharm; for example if I am writing `assert_true` without having it imported, then I can <kbd>Alt-Enter</kbd> on it and I get the suggestion to *Import from... nose.tools.assert_true* and the ide automatically adds the line:

```
from nose.tools import assert_true
```

Thats all good. But if I later write `assert_false` and press <kbd>Alt-Enter</kbd> I don't seem to have the choice to add that to the existing import automatically. Seem odd to me, do I miss something ?

So currently what I do is to add the first function like that and then I have to add additional functions manually to the existing import lines.

I know you can use * and to import the full module; but I am still interested in on how to automatically add further functions to existing import lines in some non manual way.

**Update**: as in the comments below this seem to be specific to nose.tools, when importing from other modules it works.

Comment: That's odd. I just tried it with `date` and `datetime` and it appends to `from datetime import ...` perfectly fine.

Comment: mine also works fine. Perhaps updating to the latest version?

Comment: @deceze true with classes from datetime works, maybe it's something specific to nose ? I'll see if I find more examples.

Comment: Hm no didn't find other examples now, odd though that it does not work in the case of nose.tools.

Comment: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY#newissue=yes